# Shell Script - How to compare the content of a directory from time to time

Tags: shell

I have an script that shows me the content of a directory every 2 seconds.

Now, I need to change it so I will be able to do something (e.g. echo it has changed) if the content of the directory has changed.

My script is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
MON_DIR="/home/lab"
if [ -d $MON_DIR ] ; then
    echo "Directory exists."
    while true
    do
        echo "Content of directory:"
        ls $MON_DIR
        sleep 2
    done
else
    echo "Directory does not exists." > /dev/stderr
    exit $? > /dev/stderr
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task sounds like you want to try [`watch`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-watch/): It can run a command periodically and show its output. Using its `-g (--chgexit)` (exit when the output changes), you could try achieve what you want. I am thinking along the lines of (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
MON_DIR="/home/lab"
if [ -d $MON_DIR ] ; then
    echo "Directory exists."
    while true
    do
        watch -n 2 -g "ls ${MON_DIR}" > /dev/null
        echo "Content has changed."            
    done
else
    echo "Directory does not exists." > /dev/stderr
    exit $? > /dev/stderr
fi
```

I am suppressing output of `watch` here, to ensure you will be able to see the message. you might also replace the infinite loop (`while true`) with something that can be better aborted: Ctrl+C will abort `watch` and the loop will restart it. Thus you would have to hit Ctr+C twice in a short interval.